# Including figures caption on a separate tex file?

Tags: graphics, captions, subfiles

I am using overleaf, the compiler is pdflatex. I have a main.tex and then a file.tex for each of my section, all glued together with the package subfiles.

I would like to avoid interruptint the text of my different sections with a figure code block. Therefore I created a figures.tex where I put the figure code. However, compiling the main.tex result in the figure not being found

Here is my main.tex

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

%% Language and font encodings
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\setlength{\parindent}{4em}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}


%% Sets page size and margins
\usepackage[a4paper,top=2.5cm,bottom=2cm,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}
%% Useful packages
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}

\title{Thesis}
\author{Alessandro D.}

\begin{document}
\graphicspath{{images/}{../images/}}
\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\subfile{sections/introduction}

\bibliographystyle{abbrv}
\bibliography{sample}

\end{document}
```

then I have a subfolder called sections and a subfolder called images with the png images. Here an example where I run into troubles:

```
\documentclass[../main.tex]{subfiles}
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
blabla
Some examples of trophi can be seen in \autoref{fig:trophi.png} 
blabbla
\end{document}
```

And here is the figures.tex

```
\documentclass[../main.tex]{subfiles}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{trophi.png}
\caption{\textbf{Bwise haplotypes}. SEM microscopy from \cite{melone_trophi_2005} of different bdelloid trophi.}
\label{fig:trophi}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Compiling the main.tex has the following result

```
Some examples of trophi can be seen in?? bla-bla-bla
```

No figure is displayed, it doesn't seem to be able to find it.

So is it possible to achieve this?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! I may have misunderstood something, but I don't see where `figures.tex` is being called up either in `main.tex` or in `introduction.tex`. Perhaps you need an `\input{../images/figures.tex}` command somewhere to get this working? Note: `\autoref` will only paste a reference to something. You still need to have that something explicitly included somewhere.

Comment: That's probably the key but I can't figure out what command and where. Note that the arborescence is: sections/figures.tex. I added \input{sections/figures} in the introduction.tex and now it compiles and the image is included at the end of the document but still not referenced (??) in the text.

Comment: `\autoref{fig:trophi}` is not going to insert the figure for you: all it does is insert the number of the figure in which `\label{fig:trophi}` is written. Note: you currently have `\autoref{fig:trophi.png}` so you need to delete the `.png` to match the `\label` command. If you have lots of different figures and put them all inside the same `figures.tex` then they will all appear in the same place (namely, wherever you include the `figures.tex` subfile). You will probably need `\subfile{figure1}`, then `\subfile{figure2}` and so on, at the point in your text where you want the figure to appear.

Comment: Indeed, that's correct, I think I am on the right path now, thanks for pointing it to me.